# Computing marginal PDF from joint PDF when x and y are related

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, density-function, marginal-distribution

We have $f_{X,Y} = cxy$ when $0 \le x \le y \le 1$ (and $f_{X,Y} = 0$ otherwise). $c$ is a normalization constant.

I'm trying to compute the marginal PDF of $Y$ from the above.

To find the marginal PDF of $Y$, we're going to integrate the joint PDF over $x$, but I'm not sure over which range we're integrating?

- Is the integration range for the computation $[0, y]$ (the values $x$ can take) or is it $[0,1]$?
- What is the marginal PDF of $Y$?
- Over which range is the resulting marginal PDF of $Y$ defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ can realise values between $0$ and $1$.

When $Y$ has a particular value of $y$, then $X$ shall have some value $x$ where $0\leqslant x\leqslant y$.

Thus:

$$\begin{align}f_{\small Y}(y)&=\int_\Bbb R c x y\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant 1}\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&= cy\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y\leqslant 1}\int_0^y x\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the bold "1" with subtext. I've not come across that notation before.

Comment: If we continue from there, would it be correct to say that $f_Y(y) = 1/2 * c * y^3$ ?

Comment: It is an Indicator random variable, taking on a value of $1$ when the indexed event occurs, or $0$ when it does not. Basically a piecewise function. So :-$$\begin{align}f_{\small Y}(y)&=(cy^3/2)\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y\leqslant 1}\\&=\begin{cases} cy^3/2&:& 0\leqslant y\leqslant 1\\ 0&:& \textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align}$$